# FileBeat Not Starting Inside Docker Container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, .net-core, dockerfile, filebeat

We have created a DockerFile to run a application along with FileBeat. The Docker Image is being successfully built and when I start the container my application is running fine. However FileBeat is not starting when the container starts.

We have to manually start FileBeat Service by using docker exec.

Below is my Docker File.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0.3
COPY pub/ /app/
WORKDIR /app

WORKDIR /usr/local/filebeat

RUN curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-6.2.4-amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i filebeat-6.2.4-amd64.deb

CMD service filebeat start

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Application.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

CMD and entrypoint are the two components in what a Docker image will do when run. It looks like you are trying to use CMD to start a service *before* launching your application. That's not what it does and I'd encourage you to read about this here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd. Instead what you want is to look at ways of running multiple services in the same container.

Here is a summary of ways to start multiple services in a single Docker container: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Often the best thing to do is to run one process per container, but sometimes that's not feasible so either using a shell script to launch both processes or something more heavyweight (like supervisord).

The simple way using a script (inlined from that Docker docs page) which you make the entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start the first process
./my_first_process -D
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start my_first_process: $status"
  exit $status
fi

# Start the second process
./my_second_process -D
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start my_second_process: $status"
  exit $status
fi
```